# tomcat 8 returning 404 for all 400 level responses

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm running tomcat 8.5.6.  When my Jersey rest service returns a 400 or 409 (I debugged into the code to verify this is happening) Tomcat is returning a 404 response (verified in Tomcat localhost access log and in browser).

When I change that same service to return a 500 in those same situations the 500 is being returned to the browser.

Any thoughts on why Tomcat is absorbing all 400 level responses and turning them into 404s and how I get Tomcat to return the desired response codes?  Thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure how this is a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I added some body content to the response and the correct codes started flowing back to the client.

```
    } catch (UserAlreadyExistsException e) {
        LOG.error(e, "user already exists");
        response = Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity("user already exists").build();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOG.error(e, "bad request");
        response = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e, "server error");
        response = Response.serverError().entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }

    return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat new version make more stricter validate in http header, you may add one more "host" or missing "host" in your header param. I have the same problem and I remove the duplicate